# Why is the cross entropy of the same probability distribution not 0?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, distributions, cross-entropy

From what I've been reading, if there is no underlying difference between the 2 probabilities distributions we would have perfect entropy.

I'm putting an example below. Can anybody explain why the cross entropy of two exactly equal probability distributions is not 0 here?

```
### example of calculating cross entropy for identical distributions
from math import log2

### calculate cross-entropy
def cross_entropy(p, q):
    return -sum([p[i]*log2(q[i]) for i in range(len(p))])

### define data
p = [0.10, 0.40, 0.50]
# calculate cross entropy H(P, P)
ce_pp = cross_entropy(p, p)

print('H(P, P): %.3f bits' % ce_pp)
```

**Result = 1.36**

Comment: Considering just the *definition* of cross-entropy, for which values $p_i$ and $q_i$ will the cross-entropy be exactly 0?

Comment: If the distributions are the same, cross entropy becomes entropy. It's the KL divergence that should be $0$ when they're the same. And, the distributions you give are not the same.

Comment: I used P twice to calculate it but didn't use Q. I'm going to take out Q in an edit so that it's more clear

Comment: Let's take $i=1$.  What is `p[i]*log2(p[i])`?

Comment: It would be 0.4 * log2 0.4 = -0.528

Comment: I think @jbowman means "Suppose that $p$ is a scalar. What is $H(p,p)$?" (Hint: $\sum_i p_i = 1.$)

Comment: @Sycorax - yes, thanks for clarifying that!

Comment: @Sycorax I apologize, I'm not very proficient in Math, I believe the answer to the question is that entropy in itself is just a measure of the information given by the distribution and that the KL divergence would be the one that makes sense being 0.

Comment: Try drawing a plot of $-p \log p$. Where is it 0? Can you generalize to a case where $p$ is a vector with 2 elements?

Comment: @Earlien, please stop editing this post to add the R tag. It's blatantly not using the R language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can see that your understanding is not correct by inspecting the **definition** of cross-entropy: $$H(p,q)=-\sum_i p_i \log q_i .$$

- The function $f(q) = -\log(q)$ is zero only for $q=1$. It's sufficient to observe that the function is monotonic and therefore has *at most* 1 zero.
- The function $g(p) = p$ is zero only for $p=0$.

So we know that to achieve $H(p,q)=0$, we require some configuration of $p_i=0$ or $q_i=1$. The example in OP's post doesn't have any $p_i=0$ or $q_i=1$, so the claim in the question is false.

An example of $p,q$ that have $H(p,q)=0$ is $p = [0, 1]$ and $q=[0,1]$.

(Note that *not every* choice that has some $p_i=0$ or $q_i=1$ will have $H(p,q)=0$.)